# What is the bare minimum data I would need to import from an OSM data file in order to geocode an address?

Tags: openstreetmap, geocoding, osm2pgsql

I'm using osm2pgsql to import an extract of OpenStreetMap's data so I can geocode an address to a lat/lng. But I'm new to OSM and mapping so I'm having trouble figuring out what data is relevant and what is unnecessary.

What is the bare minimum data I would need to import from an OSM data file in order to geocode an address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at [nominatim/gazetteer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) and dive in the code to find out, I've done so a while back but there are steps to create certain indexes that you need to find data (geocode and reverse geocode).   So directly it's hard to tell what you really need.